# What happens when functional dependency is circular?

Tags: database, 3nf, canonical-form

I am trying to decompose the following relationships in to 3NF:

```
A -> BCD
BC -> DE
C -> D
D -> A
```

So I eliminated the redundancy to get the canonical cover:

```
A -> BC
B -> E
C -> D
D -> A
```

And now I am trying to decompose this into 3NF.

Should I decompose into `r1(A, B, C) r2(B, D), r3(C, D)`. Then what do I do with `D -> A`?

The fact that `A -> B -> D -> A` is throwing me off.

Comment: Circular references are quite valid. Many real-world data-model's employ them.

Comment: I just don't know how I should decompose the relation.

Comment: This article may help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/07/01/10033575.aspx Practically speaking, there are to be avoided (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38655/Prevent-Circular-References-in-Database-Design).

Comment: "So I eliminated the redundancy to get the canonical cover. . ." What happened to "E"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
A -> BCD
BC -> DE
C -> D
D -> A
```

to obtain a canonical cover we first remove D from BC->DE:

```
A -> BC
BC -> E
C -> D
D -> A
```

Next, we observe that C->D, D->A, A->BC and if we know B->E, then we also know C->E. Hence,

```
A -> BC
B -> E
C -> D
D -> A
```

3NF decomposition works as follows:

1) Create tables for each dependency in the canonical cover

```
R1(A,B,C) R2(B,E) R3(C,D) R4(A,D)
```

2) Determine candidate keys of R. If no candidate keys are contained in the tables of step 1, add a new table containing only attributes of a candidate key.

Here A is a candidate key and it is contained in R1 (and R4), so no new tables should be added.

3) If there is a table such that its attributes are a subset of attributes of another table, remove the "contained" table.

This is not applicable, so the 3NF decomposition remains unchanged.

As you see, circular dependencies are not problematic.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I think in BC -> E, B instead of C is extraneous. Let F denote the original cover, according to the extraneous eliminating algorithm, C -> E is in the closure of F, but B -> E is not; thus B is extraneous.